# Why does 'module load intel' fail to load libfftw3?

Tags: linux, cluster, hpc, intel

I am in a cluster (centos) trying to run a program (pw.x) that requires loading three modules: intel, impi, and quantum-espresso. Now, I am getting an error saying

```
pw.x: error while loading shared libraries: libfftw3.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, I ran a `ldd pw.x` command to check what happened, and I saw that:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff81583000)
...
libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.so => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.243/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.so (0x00007fe15c6ea000)
libfftw3.so.3 => Not found
...
```

According to the instruction given [here](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/pw_user_guide/node21.html#SECTION00060010000000000000), I tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and export it from inside the job script as follows, but it didn't work.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

(because the missing libfftw3.so.3 library is inside /lib64/). When I checked the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it successfully added the /lib64 part but still I get the same error.
My question is what could be the reason for this error? Is it a problem of the cluster (so that I need the root privileges to fix it)? or is it a problem that can be fixed without root privileges?

Comment: Is `/lib64` actually in file system root `/`, or somewhere deeper like `/var/ib`? If it's not in the root try exporting with full path, like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/lib64`.

Comment: @Peregrino69 yes, it is in `/` of the head node. I am confused because this is a cluster, so I am not sure if the computing node can reach this `/` of head node. But again, for all other shared libraries, it worked pretty well. It's only not working for libfftw3. For other libraries, I didn't even have to export anything, simply loading the intel module takes care of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: OK. I'm sorry I can't help you further, don't know jack abt this. Just wanted to clarify that... wouldn't be the first time something really basic goes unnoticed :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 true :) thanks for trying.